# N1QL: add new object to existed couchbase document

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++, database, nosql

Is it possible using N1QL?

For example i have this:

```
{
"blog": "Coffee",
"user_id": 41,
"comments": [
    {
        "comment": "cup",
        "user_id": 883
    },
    {
        "comment": "water",
        "user_id": 790
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want using N1QL add sugar to comments, to result this:
    {
    "blog": "Coffee",
    "user_id": 41,
    "comments": [
        {
            "comment": "cup",
            "user_id": 883
        },
        {
            "comment": "water",
            "user_id": 790
        },
        {
            "comment": "sugar",
            "user_id": 14
        }
      ]
    }

I tried this:

```
UPDATE
    Blog
SET
    `c.comment` = "sugar",
    `c.user_id` = 14
FOR
    c IN comments
WHERE 
    `blog` = "Coffee" 
// [{"code":3000,"msg":"syntax error - at WHERE"}
```

And this:

```
UPDATE 
    Blog
SET
    ("comments", { "comment": "sugar", "user_id": 14})
WHERE
    `blog` = "Coffee"
//[{"code":3000,"msg":"syntax error - at ("}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can perform any modification using N1QL.

```
UPDATE Blog
SET comments = ARRAY_APPEND( comments, { "comment":"sugar", "user_id":14 } )
WHERE blog = "Coffee";
```